# Running a background process in container during one step in docker build

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dockerfile, background-process, docker-build

I'd like to run integration tests of an app during `docker build`. These tests require a Redis server being available.

How can I run `redis-server` and keep it running in the background during the integration-test step, i.e. `gradle build`?

Here is the essence of my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# apt-get install stuff
# ...
# install gradle
# build and install redis

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

# TODO: start redis-server

# run unit tests / integration tests of app
RUN /opt/gradle/gradle-4.6/bin/gradle build --info

# TODO: stop redis-server

# build app
RUN ./gradlew assemble

# start app with
# docker run
CMD ["java", "-jar", "my_app.jar"]
```

Comment: I wouldn't do it this way. I would produce the image and then take the image through a CI process, in which it will only be pushed to your image registry if it passes the tests. That will allow you to spin up a separate Redis image, rather than installing Redis in an image where it doesn't belong.

Answer (score 20):

As [halfer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472495/halfer) states in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50211207/running-a-background-process-in-container-during-one-step-in-docker-build#comment87439931_50211207), this is not good practice.

However for completeness I want to share a solution to the original question nevertheless:

```
RUN nohup bash -c "redis-server &" && sleep 4 && /opt/gradle/gradle-4.6/bin/gradle build --info
```

This runs `redis-server` only for this single layer. The `sleep 4` is just there to give redis enough time start up.

So the `Dockerfile` then looks as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# apt-get install stuff
# ...
# install gradle
# build and install redis

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

# run unit tests / integration tests of app
RUN nohup bash -c "redis-server &" && sleep 4 && /opt/gradle/gradle-4.6/bin/gradle build --info

# TODO: uninstall redis

# build app
RUN ./gradlew assemble

# start app with
# docker run
CMD ["java", "-jar", "my_app.jar"]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! The code `RUN nohup sh -c "redis-server &" && sleep 4 && awk ... | redis-cli --pipe && redis-cli save` exactly what I need. I used this line in `FROM redis as convert` phase and then in `FROM redis as final` just `COPY --from=convert /data/dump.rdb` to initialize redis without any uninsatll steps.